# Making Azure cognitive search precise

Tags: c#, azure, bing-api

Have implemented [Bing Web Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/web-search-sdk-quickstart) on my website, but I want to limit random results and make the search more precise.

Here are the accepted search scenarios.

1. Limiting the results to my site, for example `www.stackoverflow.com`
2. Then show the searches from a specific subsite `www.stackoverflow.com/language/foo/bar` first followed by other sites under same domain

Here's the code

```
        public static async Task<SearchResultModel> WebResultsWithCountAndOffset(WebSearchClient client, string searchQuery,int pageNumber)
        {
            SearchResultModel model = new SearchResultModel();

            List<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
            try
            {
                var offset = (pageNumber-1) * 20;
                var webData = await client.Web.SearchAsync(query: searchQuery.Replace(' ', '+') + " domain:stackoverflow.com OR site:www.stackoverflow.com/language/foo/bar", offset: offset, count: 20, textFormat: "HTML", textDecorations: true, countryCode: "US"); 
                if (webData?.WebPages?.Value?.Count > 0)
                {
                    model.totalCount = webData.WebPages.TotalEstimatedMatches;
                    var WebPagesResult = webData.WebPages.Value.ToList();
                    var ds = webData.SpellSuggestions;
                    foreach(var d in WebPagesResult)
                    {
                        SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
                        result.PageURL = d.Url;
                        result.Snippet = d.Snippet;
                        result.Title = d.Name;
                        searchResults.Add(result);
                    }
                    model.list = searchResults;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Didn't see any Web data..");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Encountered exception. " + ex.Message);
            }
            return model;
        }
```

I can see the data coming in, but to me it doesn't seem relevant. Domain limitation works well, however the ordering and precision of results is still irrelevant. Please note that the domain I'm referring to can have thousand of pages indexed, but the precision looks completely off the track.

Comment: Be careful with the product names that you are using: you did not deploy Azure Cognitive Search, but Bing Search. Azure Cognitive Search is another product https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/services/search/

Answer (score 0):

For the site limitation, use `site:` as indicated in the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference#query-parameters?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365) ("q" field) and [here](https://help.bing.microsoft.com/#apex/18/en-US/10001/-1). But be careful as there is a limit of 2 levels deep max:

> You can use site: to search for web domains, top level domains, and
> directories that are not more than two levels deep.

So remove your "domain:..." from your query to avoid unnecessary results. For your "precision" question, what do you mean by "more precise" here?

Comment: using ```site``` keyword makes it more irrelevant, I've tried that before posting the question :) , infact I'm using both ```domain:``` as well as ```site:```. When I say "more precise", I mean, if I search for ```battery```, I seem to see the results not having ```battery``` anywhere as topmost results, but I do see results related to ```battery``` after a few irrelevant results, so I just want to have them listed in proper order. Is there anything like scoring based on how close it matches to the question, so that I can re-order accordingly?